# Baselineskip varies when using linguex.sty uses

Tags: vertical-alignment, linguistics, linguex, cgloss4e

My code as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{linguex}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}%
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}%

\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\exg.
Blixa fub-ax. \\
the.house dissolve.green-{\scshape past} \\
`The house dissolved into a green slimy puddle.'

\end{document}
```

Output comes fine, but the baseline space, i.e., leading space is not come correctly for both places, one place it came as 12pt and in another place it came as 11pt, but it should be as 12pt, please refer the below image for clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\\` in `linguex` (actually `cgloss4e`, the glossing macros) is not a newline but is a delimiter for the lines of the gloss. So to introduce the translation line properly, you should use the `\glt` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}%

\begin{document}
\exg.
Blixa fub-ax. \\
the.house dissolve.green-{\scshape past} \\
\glt `The house dissolved into a green slimy puddle.'

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]